# Asp.net button click populate Autocomplete for a textbox

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have created a keyboard using asp:button control. Onclientclick event it will display the corresponding text on the textbox. All these are working fine.

Needs:

1. I want to add autocomplete using jquery to a textbox. if i click the button [A] it has to display all the records with a.
2. This process is working if im using the system keyboard.

Code:

```
      <link href="CSS/jquery.autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>  

      $("#antSearchText").autocomplete('SearchAutoComplete.ashx');

     <asp:Button ID="six" runat="server" Text="6" CssClass="myclass" OnClientClick="return typeLetter(this);" />
```

Geetha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank You for all your replies. My problem resolved by using the following code to fire the event.

Code:

```
   var q = document.getElementById('txtbox');
   var evObj = document.createEventObject();
   evObj.keyCode = 84; // [T] key
   q.fireEvent('onkeydown', evObj);
```

Geetha.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation here explains how to activate autocomplete on a textbox: [JQuery Autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete). Have you tried that, and it still doesn't work?

Otherwise, can you add more information? What makes the 'system keyboard' work? What does the `typeletter` function do?

Answer (score 0):

You should return false at the end of client click event and do the textbox manipulation in typeletter function. It should look like  `OnClientClick="typeLetter(this);return false;"`

This stops the asp:button from posting back

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the plugin, by default uses the onKeyUp event (probably) which is why the system keybord would work. The API doese provide a call to trigger the search

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/search

I didn't see any thing like $(this).search() or  $('input#suggest').search(); in your function. I could have missed it though

You can probably now ignore the following!

OLD ANSWER BELOW

Try using a standard HTML button instead of an ASP:net button, if there is no other reason to use an ASP:net button control that is.